# pdfbox throwing error while trying use printFields example

Tags: pdfbox

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error: End-of-File, expected line
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.readLine(BaseParser.java:1521)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parseHeader(PDFParser.java:316)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:177)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1220)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1187)
at org.apache.pdfbox.examples.fdf.PrintFieldsOld.main(PrintFieldsOld.java:135)
```

I am trying to printFields of this pdf : http://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/files/form/i-9.pdf

I am using PrintFields.Java in the src here: 
http://pdfbox.apache.org/downloads.html

It's this zip file : 
pdfbox-1.8.5-src.zip 9.3MB, source archive, [ PGP signature ]
SHA1 checksum: fc01acc1e2575ff1f40e44e949a862fcae076029
MD5 checksum: b97c345ddbbd1457989eb206aa5cd40f

I was using 1.8.2 pdfbox version then upgraded it based on comment here :
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-1779

but still having the same issue.

Comment: The exception occurs during `PDDocument.load`. Have you tried `loadNonSeq` instead of `load`? The former is not working according to the pdf specification, the latter is better in this regard.

Comment: You were using an outdated 1.8.2 version based on a comment in PDFBOX-1779, despite that the opener of that issue wrote at the end "Not an issue with pdfbox"???  And yes, please use loadNonSeq().

Comment: I just tried to reproduce the issue doing a `PDDocument.load("i-9.pdf");` (after all the exception occurs during loading according to the stack trace). Unfortunately that call successfully loaded the document. Are you sure your copy of the document is complete?